# BeatifulSoup doesn't respect void html tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

BeatifulSoup4 seems to parse `<br>`, `<img>` and other [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) as containers:

```
html = """\
<!doctype html>
<head><title>xyz</title></head>
<p>hey</p>
line<br>
<img src='x.jpg' alt='xyz'>
<p>wtf</p>
"""

import bs4
doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)


for x in doc.children:
    print x
    print '----'
```

prints:

```
doctype html
----


----
<head><title>xyz</title></head>
----


----
<p>hey</p>
----

line
----
<br>
<img alt="xyz" src="x.jpg">
<p>wtf</p>
</img></br>
----
```

Is there an option to make BS parse these tags properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *parser* that interprets it as a container. You are essentially feeding in invalid HTML and it is then up to the parser to still make sense of it. The default [`HTMLParser.HTMLParser()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#htmlparser.HTMLParser) can only do so much with it.

[Switch parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser); you'll need to install either `lxml` or `html5lib`:

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

or

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

Demo (with `lxml`, a `<html>` and `<body>` tag is added so I drilled down first):

```
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> for x in doc.body.children:
...     print x
...     print '----'
... 
<p>hey</p>
----

line
----
<br/>
----


----
<img src="x.jpg"/>
----


----
<p>wtf</p>
----


----
```

The `html5lib` is exactly the same here; it is the slowest option of the three supported HTML parsers, but also the most accurate in reproducing what browsers do with broken HTML.

Note that the `DocType` handling is a little odd in BeautifulSoup; like `Comment`, `ProcessingInstruction`, `CData` and `Declaration` elements the `str()` version of the elements show *just* the string contents, not including the prefix and postfix. Use `NavigableString.output_ready()` to include those:

```
>>> next(doc.children)
u'html'
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> next(doc.children)
u'doctype html'
>>> type(next(doc.children))
<class 'bs4.element.Doctype'>
>>> next(doc.children).output_ready()
u'<!DOCTYPE doctype html>\n'
```

`lxml` doesn't include the declaration in the tree, but `html5lib` does.

Comment: So, "batteries included", but some of them discharged )) Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: @georg: they are only 9-volt batteries. You needed the Li-Ion 2000mAh option. Note that recent versions of Python have come forward in great strides in parsing broken HTML, it used to be that many pages were entirely unparsable by the stdlib. :-)

Comment: Actually, I don't think the problem is that my html is invalid. HTMLParser fails to parse totally valid markup as well. I've edited the question to make the point clear.

Comment: @georg: the markup isn't valid, actually; leaving empty tags opened (like the `<br>` and `<img>` tags is not valid. The doctype is HTML5 and the parser in the stdlib is only rated for HTML 2.0 and 'many HTML 3.0 and 3.2 elements'.

Comment: @georg: apologies, had my html parser libs mixed up; `htmlparser` is used, not `htmllib`.

Comment: @georg: and in BeautifulSoup the Doctype, ProcessingInstruction and Comment types do not include the surrounding markup in the `str()` version; so you are printing not an element there but the `DocType` object without the `<!DOCTYPE` prefix and `>` suffix.

Comment: `<br>` and `<img>` have been around since 1990s and this markup is totally ok according to the w3c validator. I've also checked with html4 and 3 doctypes, and the std parser failed on those as well. It's the parser that is broken, not the markup.

Comment: @georg: this looks like a BeautifulSoup issue actually; see [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue14786); the parser issues an open tag but no close tag event.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because it helped fixing my issue, but I'd edit it a bit to outline that the actual source of the problem is a bug in BS (or HTMLparser).

Comment: @georg: the interplay between HTMLParser and BeautifulSoup for problematic HTML code. Once you install `lxml` it is made the default anyway, which is what I'd recommend for any serious HTML parsing tasks.